# Inserting Character array into hashmap

Tags: java, arrays, concurrency, hashmap

I have a wordcount program where I am reading from a character array, and inserting every word found (checking for blankspace) into a `HashMap<Character[], Integer>`, where the first parameter is the word, and the second parameter is the number of times it has been found.

I do not use StringBuilder or Tokenizer because I am avoiding using Strings, as I am reading a 10gb file, and since Strings are immutable, it seems to cause memory issues.

The following code seems to lag after reading only 20-30mb of the file. The problem seems to be that my key is a `Character[]`, so my get statement ALWAYS returns null. Not sure how to fix this without using Strings.

Note - I build the word using an `ArrayList<Character>` - I then convert the array list into a `Character []`. I do this because inserting an ArrayList into a HashMap is quite problematic when check for equality. Also, this program is multithreaded, and each thread has its own hashmap.

```
public void run() {
        int i = 0;  Integer check;
        ArrayList<Character> charBuilder = new ArrayList<Character>();
        Character [] inserter;
        for (i = 0; i < newbyte.length; i++) {
            if(newbyte[i] != ' ') {
                charBuilder.add(newbyte[i]);
            }
            else { //delimiter found, insert word into local hashmap, clear builder
                   //convert to char [] first
                inserter = charBuilder.toArray(new Character[charBuilder.size()]);
                check = map.get(inserter);
                if (check != null) { //already exists an entry
                    map.put(inserter, check + 1);
                }
                else {
                    map.put(inserter, 1);
                }
                charBuilder.clear();
                inserter = null;
            }
        }
```

And the constructor

```
BigCountThread3(char[] newbyte, 
        HashMap<Character[], Integer> hashMap) {
```

Comment: Strings being immutable has nothing to do with the problems you see.  maybe memory might be a problem since a String takes up more memory than a `char[]` since it's an Object wrapping a `char[]`.

Comment: I assume you are reading the 10GB file line-by-line.  ie not keeping the lines of the file around.  It should be no problem to count the words in the file.  All you'll have in memory are the unique words plus overhead.

Comment: My problem with using `String` is that I have 4 threads running at the same time, creating hundreds of new strings every seconds, and inserting them into `HashMap`. For example, I might have `string = "token"` and then a second later `string = "token2"`. Even though I am re-using the variable, both take up memory due to the immutable attribute of a String. With four threads going as fast as they can, I run out of memory very quickly.

Maybe there is another reason that happens, but that was my observation when I first tackled this problem using a `HashMap<String, Integer>`

Comment: You could try doing this without multithreading first.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is char[] equals. You are putting a character array as the key and when you try to get the key from a map the equals method for the key is called. Since char array equals will be true only if the two keys are pointing to the same reference and it will not work if you create the same character array since those will be two different arrays with same characters.

Additionally i think putting array as key in the map is a bad idea.

Comment: I see that being a problem. Not sure what to do about it.

Comment: You may have to create a class that encapsulates char array, and implements a equals/hashcode... but basically, you would rewrite String!